# Would MongoDB be better than SQL Server for this query?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mongodb

I have a query that uses a `DBGeography` type named `locationpoints` in my address table. The query looks something like this.

```
From u in context.YogaSpaces
Where u.YogaSpaces.Addresses.LocationPoints(somePoints) < 5000
Select u.YogaSpaces
```

Using Entity Framework code first I can't create an index on `LocationPoints`. So I'm wondering if I should explore MongoDB for its ability to index spatial data or look at some other way to create an index in SQL Server without code first w/ Entity Framework. If 99% of the queries are fetching data will Mongo be a better fit overall?

Any advice here is appreciated.

Comment: MongoDB does not support multiple points in a geonear query as of yet, despite supporting the storing of multiple points within a document and for that to be indexed correctly. This means you will need to change your query, if you could then there is a chance MongoDB could be a fit but really, this is a very vague question and hard to answer. You need to test it

Comment: Thats correct EF is not a tool for creating indexes. Create them in the correct tool - SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

What would it exactly mean "better"? If it's all about speed then it shoudld be  possible to create spatial indexes in on SQL Server (I have no clue how it's done using EF). At least [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-spatial-indexes) tells so. Quick extract:

> Spatial Data in SQL Server has special indexing because it has to perform 
>   specialised functions.
>
> SQL Server’s spatial data type allows us to store spatial objects and
>   make them available to an application. SQL Server supports two spatial
>   data types:
>
> - **Geometry:** Stores the X and Y coordinates that represents lines,    points, or polygons
> - **Geography:** Stores the latitude and longitude coordinates that    represent lines, points, or polygons.

Perhaps it's something you should look at, if you didn't already?

If you would share some test data and use cases, then I could try to help you (and myself) more (It's quite an interesting question, lad!)